# OpenVPN - possible to log failed authentications?

Tags: authentication, openvpn

I do not know how the OpenVPN authentication protocol works in detail, which is why I am wondering if there is a possibility to log failed authentications.

E.g. if I try to use a invalid key file.
I tried it on my own with a changed key file and I got an error on the client side, but my OpenVPN server seems to log only the successful authentication attempts.

Is there a way to log these failed authentications or is this now needed for a secure server (if so, why?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might be able to see them by adding `verb 5` on your config more info [about verb](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html)

Comment: The log is getting fuller now, but still not logging failed auths

Answer (score 1):

Set the appropriate level of log file verbosity for both server and client side

in server.conf and client.conf

`verb 6`

5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
9 is extremely verbose

verb 6 and above in your situation should help.
Regards